# Paypal case closed, but problem is not resolved

Tags: paypal

I missed some important information from dispute, but case is already closed by Paypal. How could I reopen it or add some additional information?

Answer (score 1):

According to [PayPal's website](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/can-i-reopen-a-closed-dispute-faq809) you cannot.

The only other option is to call them and persuade them to reopen, or start a new dispute.

Comment: I cannot open also a new dispute for the same transaction.

Comment: You can't, but perhaps they will if you provide enough convincing arguments by phone.